# No android platform shown in SDK Manager on Mac

Tags: android, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I have installed  Android SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.

I have created the .bash_profile and updated it with the path where i have the "android-sdk-macosx" folder.
But when I open the SDK manager to install a platform, it does not locate it. I connect using a proxy, which I have entered in the Preferences.

Kindly help. 
Should I install some other SDK version. Are there any compatibility issues ? Why does it not connect to the internet in spite of mentioning the proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the sdk is configured in the eclipse preferences

```
Configuring the ADT Plugin

After you've successfully downloaded the ADT as described above, 
the next step is to modify your ADT preferences in Eclipse to point to the 
Android SDK directory:

Select Window > Preferences... to open the Preferences panel (Mac OS X: 
Eclipse > Preferences).
Select Android from the left panel.
You may see a dialog asking whether you want to send usage statistics to Google. 
If so,     make your choice and click Proceed. You cannot continue with this 
procedure  
until you click Proceed.

For the SDK Location in the main panel, click Browse... and locate your 
downloaded SDK directory. Click Apply, then OK.

Done! If you haven't encountered any problems, then the installation is complete.
If you're installing the Android SDK for the first time, return to Installing 
the SDK to 
complete your setup.*emphasized text*
```